# Spring Beans Scope - taking into account Controllers \ Services \ Repositories

Tags: spring, scope, singleton, prototype

I'm having 1 @Controller bean in my project
and 2 @Service  beans that this controller calls.

the services using 2 different @Repository beans for persisting.

My question is :

my server is about to get hundreds of calls simultaniously, isnt it "awkward" that all my beans i described above are of scope="singleton"? should i use "prototype" instead? or maybe spring does it automatically ?

Answer (score 1):

I think in both cases you wil have the same number of objects.

> The non-singleton, prototype scope of bean deployment results in the
>   creation of a new bean instance every time a request for that specific
>   bean is made **(that is, it is injected into another bean or it is
>   requested via a programmatic getBean() method call on the
>   container)**. As a rule of thumb, you should use the prototype scope
>   for all beans that are stateful, while the singleton scope should be
>   used for stateless beans.

Answer (score 0):

in Spring by default all beans it is "singleton" and should be in most cases.

Comment: that's not a very informative remark. can you provide some more info?